# MVC @html.textboxfor prepopulating with Guid default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, guid, html.textboxfor

**My controller:**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult AddEstablishment()
 {     
    return View("AddEstablishment",new EstablishmentModel());
 }
```

**My model:**

```
public class EstablishmentModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Establishment ID")]
    public Guid EstablishmentId { get; set; }
    .............
```

**My AddEstablishment View:**

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EstablishmentId, new { @id = "inputEstGuid", @class = "input input-xlarge", @placeholder = "5C3B1CBC-2574-4E2A-A9FA-A8CA0041AB86" })
```

**Result:**

[image]

*My textbox is prepopulating with the Guid default value*

`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

**How can i avoid it?**

***Please note there are obvious reasons why I'm passing an instance of the model to the view.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't this work?

```
 public Guid? EstablishmentId { get; set; }
```

Just ensure that the value is null when you initially display your view.

Comment: No additional checks are needed to ensure if value is null or not. just changing to nullable Guid will do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't suggesting additional code. I was just making sure you, as a programmer, knew the value would be null when you bound it to your textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the model into the view, it will work if you don't pass it

If you really have to, do this:

```
private string _establishmentIdAsString = string.Empty;
[Display(Name = "Establishment ID")]
public string EstablishmentIdAsString
{
    get
    {
        return _establishmentIdAsString;
    }
    set
    {
        _establishmentIdAsString = value;
        EstablishmentId = new Guid(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try, I have to pass model to view for some reasons.

Comment: If it's an empty model you don't have to, it just instanciates a new model when it's rendering the view